# Error Loading system.data.sqlite.dll in windows 7 64 bit with IE 64 bit add ins

Tags: .net, internet-explorer, sqlite, add-in

I create a Ad-dins for IE on development machine windows xp 32 bit
this ad-dins working well and load system.data.sqlite.dll in windos 7 32 bit but also working well with windows 7 64 bit with 32 bit browser but issues is here it gives error with windows 7 64 bit with IE 64 bit

issuses.................................

```
System.BadImageFormatException: 
Could not load file or assembly 'System.Data.SQLite, Version=1.0.65.0, Culture=neutral,
 PublicKeyToken=db937bc2d44ff139' or one of its dependencies. An attempt was made to load a program with an incorrect format.
File name: 'System.Data.SQLite,
 Version=1.0.65.0,
 Culture=neutral, 
 PublicKeyToken=db937bc2d44ff139'
```

............................................................

Deployment options
if select target X86 during built in .net addins failed to load in Windows 7 64 bit with IE 64 bit
but select build option  "Any cpu" addins load but above error occurs
Please suggest me what to do.

Answer (score 3):

You can't run 32-bit code in a 64-bit process.

The **Any CPU** platform configuration compiles your code for use in both 32-bit and 64-bit processes.  However, your code references an external DLL, System.Data.SQLite, that was compiled as 32-bit code.  That's where the failure occurs.

Download both the 32-bit and 64-bit versions of System.Data.SQLite.  Make two platform configurations: **x86** and **x64**.  In **x86**, include all 32-bit versions of external libraries.  In **x64**, include all 64-bit versions of external libraries.

Comment: I get system.data.sqlite.dll  source code and compiled it in our development system as Any CPU .after that get refrence in projec .But get sme errorSystem.BadImageFormatException: 
Could not load file or assembly 'System.Data.SQLite, Version=1.0.65.0, Culture=neutral,
 PublicKeyToken=db937bc2d44ff139' or one of its dependencies. An attempt was made to load a program with an incorrect format.
File name: 'System.Data.SQLite,
 Version=1.0.65.0,
 Culture=neutral, 
 PublicKeyToken=db937bc2d44ff139'

Comment: I get source code of system.data.sqlite.dll and compiled as Any cpu then get reference in project of system.data.sqlite.dll but same type of error occures 

    `code` System.BadImageFormatException: 
Could not load file or assembly 'System.Data.SQLite, Version=1.0.65.0, Culture=neutral,
 PublicKeyToken=db937bc2d44ff139' or one of its dependencies. An attempt was made to load a program with an incorrect format.
File name: 'System.Data.SQLite,
 Version=1.0.65.0,
 Culture=neutral, 
 PublicKeyToken=db937bc2d44ff139'

Comment: What DLLs does SQLite depend on?  Could one of them be 32-bit?  Is the SQLite code in C++ or C#?  C++ code cannot be compiled for Any CPU, unlike C# code.  Use the Configuration Manager (Build menu) to see (and set) which platform SQLite is actually being compiled for.

Comment: I just got this error and this is exactly the solution - no need to recompile, just copy the X64 version of the DLL (included in the bin download) over the top on 64 bit machines :) Thanks Hand-E-Food